# Yet another "ERROR 1005 can't create table" question

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

Well, I've been looking at the ERROR 1005 questions, but I haven't been able to see my error among the issues addressed by those questions. This code is generated by MySQL Workbench under Linux. Can anyone with sharp eyes spot the error? It occurs when trying to create `AB_test_questions`.

For context, table `ABs` refers to subjects of an [A/B test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing), and `AB_test_questions` represents questions which compare two subjects against each other (hence two foreign keys referencing the `ABs` table).

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`ABs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = 'represents the subject of an AB test';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`AB_test_questions` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AB1` INT NOT NULL,
  `AB2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `AB1_idx` (`AB1` ASC),
  INDEX `AB2_idx` (`AB2` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AB_test_questions_ABs_id1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AB1`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`ABs` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AB_test_questions_ABs_id2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AB2`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`ABs` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = 'represents an AB test question';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the ten options listed in that link apply to the code here?

Comment: Oh, no, my mistake. The answer was #5; foreign key `ON DELETE SET NULL` conlicts with `NOT NULL` constraint on primary key on referenced table. If you paste that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a cascade ON DELETE SET NULL, but the relevant key field is set to NOT NULL. You can fix this by either changing your cascade or setting the field to allow NULL values.

Ref:- http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/